# Como fazer a intersecção de cada posição na minha lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tentei das seguintes formas me baseando em respostas conseguidas aqui no fórum.

Primeira forma:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,3,5,7,8,9,10,20],[4,5,7,13,16,20,21,30]]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
C = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
D = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

def contagem_interseccao(a,b,c,d):
    s = set(a)
    return len(s.intersection(b,c,d))

print(contagem_interseccao(A,B,C,D))
```

Segunda forma:

```
A = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),(1,3,5,7,8,9,10,20),(4,5,7,13,16,20,21)
B = 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9
C= 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
D=  20,21,22,23,24,25

def contagem_interseccao(a, b,c,d):
    s = set(a)
    return len(s.intersection(b,c,d)) 

print(contagem_interseccao(A, B,C,D))
```

Terceira forma:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,3,5,7,8,9,10,20],[4,5,7,13,16,20,21,30]]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
C = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
D = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

n = len(set(A) & set(B))
l = len(set(A) & set(C))
k = len(set(A) & set(D))

print(list(n,l,k))
```

Eu esperava a seguinte resposta:

```
[9 1 0, 6 1 1, 3 2 3]
```

Em 2 casos o erro é sempre o mesmo: TYPE ERROR: `UNHASHABLE TYPE: "LIST"`

E em 1 caso o resultado é 0.

Este uso do set esta errado? Estou no caminho correto? Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Grato.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A questão é que seu objeto A é uma lista de listas. Apenas é possível gerar o objeto `set` a partir de tipos *hashables*, mas como a lista é um tipo mutável, ela não é *hashable*, como a mensagem de erro afirma.

Imagine que você possuísse a lista [[1], [1, 2]] e que pudesse gerar um conjunto a partir dela:

```
>>> l = [[1], [1, 2]]
>>> s = set(l)
>>> print(s)
{[1], [1, 2]}
```

O que aconteceria se adicionássemos o número 2 no primeiro elemento da lista dentro do conjunto:

```
>>> s[0].append(2)
>>> print(s)
{[1, 2], [1, 2]}
```

O que deveria acontecer com o conjunto? Você tem dois elementos iguais, então um deles seria removido? Qual? Esse é só um exemplo hipotético para explicar simploriamente como o conjunto funciona. Ele, na verdade, é uma tabela *hash* que usa o *hash*, obviamente, do objeto para identificá-lo e verificar duplicidades. Por definição, tipos mutáveis não são *hashables*, pois a cada alteração o valor de *hash* variaria.

Fora isso, sua lógica está errada. Você esta tentando comparar uma lista de listas com uma lista de inteiros. Isso faz nenhum sentido. O que você precisa fazer é comparar cada lista da listas de lista, A, com a lista de inteiros, B, C e D.

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,3,5,7,8,9,10,20], [4,5,7,13,16,20,21,30]]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
C = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
D = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

n = [len(set(a) & set(B)) for a in A]
l = [len(set(a) & set(C)) for a in A]
k = [len(set(a) & set(D)) for a in A]

print(n, l, k)
```

Mas isso gera o seguinte resultado:

```
[9, 6, 3] [1, 1, 2] [0, 1, 3]
```

E percebi que é diferente do que você esperava, pois eu comparei B, C e D com todas as listas de A em uma mesma lista. Aparentemente você esperava que `n` seria a comparação de `A[0]` com B, C e D, que `l` seria a comparação de `A[1]` com B, C e D, assim por diante. Então, uma forma de fazer seria:

```
>>> print([len(set(a) & set(i)) for a in A for i in [B, C, D]])
[9, 1, 0, 6, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Obg pela aula Anderson, digo, resposta, hahaha. Não havia entendido no inico e passei todos esse dias (noites) tentando solucionar o problema. Sua resposta me ajudou em dois importantes passos do meu projeto e ficou muito mais facil analisar os dados. Sou novo (2 meses) em programação e a forma como vc respondeu me fez ter que pesquisar e com isso aprender mais e eu te agradeço por isso tbm. Bom, é isso cara, obg mais uma vez e nos vemos pelo site, abç.